# Клиент-серверное приложение не передает строку

Tags: android, android-sdk, android-asynctask

Пишу программу на телефон, которая должна прочитать текст и txt файла и отправить его на компьютер. Она его читает, но отправить не может.

Если в print_writer.write(str); вместо str просто написать строку или передать туда любую строку не из файла, то он ее отправит.

Ошибка:
        W/System.err: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.lang.String.length()' on a null object reference

Код:
    public class Receiver_Transmitter extends AsyncTask
{

```
Socket socket;
PrintWriter print_writer;

final String LOG_TAG = "My logs";
final String file_name = "Home_Alone_File.txt";
final String DIR_SD = "Home_Alone";



@Override
protected Void doInBackground(String... urls)
{
    while(true)
    {
        @NonNull String str = "";
        int i = 0;
        String ip = null;
        String port = null;
        for (String url: urls)
        {
            if (i == 0)
            {
                ip = url;
            }
            if (i == 1)
            {
                port = url;
            }
            i++;
        }
        // Чтение данных из файла
        // Проверяем доступность SD карты.
       if (!Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED))
        {
            Log.d(LOG_TAG,"SD карта не доступна " + Environment.getExternalStorageState());
        }

        // Получаем путь к SD карте.
        File sd_patch = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        // Добавляем свой каталог к пути.
        sd_patch = new File(sd_patch.getAbsolutePath() + "/" + DIR_SD);
        // Создаем каталог.
        sd_patch.mkdirs();
        // Формируем объект File который содержит путь к файлу.
        File file_home_alone = new File(sd_patch,file_name);
        try
        {
            // Открываем поток для чтения.
            BufferedReader buffered_reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file_home_alone));
            // Читаем содержимое.
            while ((str = buffered_reader.readLine()) != null )
            {
                Log.d(LOG_TAG,str);
            }
            buffered_reader.close();

            // Отправка данных
            Log.d(LOG_TAG,str);
            Thread.sleep(10000);
            socket = new Socket(ip, Integer.parseInt(port));
            print_writer = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream());
            print_writer.write(str);
            print_writer.flush();
            print_writer.close();
            socket.close();
        }
        catch (NullPointerException exc)
        {
            exc.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (IOException exc)
        {
            exc.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (InterruptedException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Проверьте доступность сервера командой "echo test > nc ip port"

Comment: Он доступен. Я могу передать на сервер любую строку, кроме той которая прочитана из файла

Comment: Вызовите метод print() https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html#print(java.lang.String)

Comment: Так у вас в последнем проходе цикла `while` переменная `str` принимает значение null.

Comment: Спасибо) Я исправил

Answer (score 0):

А как же без `NullPointerException` здесь. Вот ваш код.

```
// Читаем содержимое.
while ((str = buffered_reader.readLine()) != null )
{
    Log.d(LOG_TAG,str);
}
```

"Крутить цикл пока не null", соответсвенно когда он докрутится, что будет в переменной `str`? Ответ в логе ошибки.

Comment: Да. Вы правы. Здесь была ошибка.

Comment: Спасибо большое

Answer (score 0):

Исправленный код:

```
public class Receiver_Transmitter extends AsyncTask<String,Void,Void>
```

{

```
Socket socket;
PrintWriter print_writer;

final String LOG_TAG = "My logs";
final String file_name = "Home_Alone_File.txt";
final String DIR_SD = "Home_Alone";



@Override
protected Void doInBackground(String... urls)
{
    StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();

    while(true)
    {
        str.delete(0,str.length());
        int i = 0;
        String ip = null;
        String port = null;
        for (String url: urls)
        {
            if (i == 0)
            {
                ip = url;
            }
            if (i == 1)
            {
                port = url;
            }
            i++;
        }
        // Чтение данных из файла
        // Проверяем доступность SD карты.
       if (!Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED))
        {
            Log.d(LOG_TAG,"SD карта не доступна " + Environment.getExternalStorageState());
        }
        // Получаем путь к SD карте.
        File sd_patch = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        // Добавляем свой каталог к пути.
        sd_patch = new File(sd_patch.getAbsolutePath() + "/" + DIR_SD);
        // Создаем каталог.
        sd_patch.mkdirs();
        // Формируем объект File который содержит путь к файлу.
        File file_home_alone = new File(sd_patch,file_name);
        try {
            // Открываем поток для чтения.
            BufferedReader buffered_reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file_home_alone));
            // Читаем содержимое.
            String line = buffered_reader.readLine();

            while (line != null)
            {
                str.append(line);
                line = buffered_reader.readLine();
                Log.d(LOG_TAG, str.toString());
            }
                Thread.sleep(100);
                socket = new Socket(ip, Integer.parseInt(port));
                print_writer = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream());
                print_writer.write(str.toString());
                print_writer.flush();
                buffered_reader.close();
                print_writer.close();
                socket.close();
        }
        catch (NullPointerException exc)
        {
            exc.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (IOException exc)
        {
            exc.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (InterruptedException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

}